# Calculate age given the birth date in the format yyyy-mm-dd

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, datetime

How can I calculate an age in years and months, given a birth date of format YYYY-MM-DD? Is it possible using the Date() function?

I have done in php. Below is my code

```
   $dateOfBirth = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($post->date_of_birth));
   $today = date("Y-m-d");
   $age= $diff->format("%Y Years, %M Months");
   echo $age;
```

I am getting the results in json.Can i embed the php code in json while diplaying or how can i get the age in years and months using date of birth....??

Comment: You can give (javascript) Date() and iso formatted date and it will create an object representation of that date.  Then you just have to do math against the current date.  Keep in mind that unless you add additional logic, the age will be based entirely upon the date settings on the clients machine.  If it is very important that the age be accurate, then you'll have to account for that, or either calcuate the age on the server side.

Comment: Is this database related by any chance?

Comment: why is this tagged as javascript and jquery?

Comment: From PHP manual user contributions 1 (http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-diff.php) https://3v4l.org/ZfCBJ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In php you can do this using the [datetime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) object:

```
$dateOfBirth = new DateTime($post->date_of_birth);
$today = new DateTime();
$diff = $today->diff($dateOfBirth);
//echo $diff->format("%Y Years, %M Months");
```

Then if you want to output that as json you can just:

```
echo json_encode(['diffString' => $diff->format("%Y Years, %M Months")]);
```

Comment: But i am using ajax and retrieving the data in json format and now i need to calculate the age from date of birth

Comment: Just send the diff in the response so you don't have to do the same work twice.

Comment: You can use array_merge php function. `array_merge(['diffString' => $diff->format("%Y Years, %M Months")], $myOtherArray)`